# Uniqueness theorem differential equations - if $y(x)\ne 0$ for some $x$, then $y(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In my calculus textbook, in the section on separable differential equations, there's a brief remark in the margin that states a seemingly important result which I cannot seem to understand:

*"If a solution $y$ is a function that satisfies $y(x) \neq 0$ for some $x$, it follows from a uniqueness theorem for solutions of differential equations that $y(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$."*

First of all, what is the unspecified *uniqueness theorem* which is mentioned? Secondly, and perhaps more importantly, I don't see how this is true. Take, for example, the differential equation

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}= \frac{x^2}{y^2}$$
with solution $y=\sqrt[3]{x^3 +8}$. If we take $y(0)=2$ as a solution, we clearly have $y(x)\neq0$ for some $x$ (in this case, for $x=0$), though it is not at all true that this implies $y(x) \neq 0$ for **all** $x$, seeing as $x=-2$ gives $y=0$ - thereby invalidating the statement by means of a counterexample.

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniqueness theorem has hypotheses, and one of those is that the right hand side of your equation
$$
y'=f(x,y)
$$
must be well-behaved in $y$. Typically, it is required that $f$ have continuous first derivatives or that $f$ be Lipschitz in $y$ in a neighborhood of the point where uniqueness is asserted. None of them is satisfied in your case near $y=0$, and the theorem does not apply.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. Does this uniqueness theorem have a name, by any chance? I'd like to follow this up with some personal research of mine, but as it stands I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Sometimes it is given the name Picard-Lindelof Theorem. See here.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem